# Error in angular 2 project, 'unexpected declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing a project in `angular 2.0`. And a error is coming up while declaring a component in `app.module` file.
I can not recognize  where I am going wrong I am using `VS code` for coding purpose.

The error is as follows-

```
dashboard:20 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'HeroDesignComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Error: Unexpected value 'HeroDesignComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'
        at eval 

(http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14725:29)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14702:56)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14625:31)
        at RuntimeCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17420:43)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17390:37)
        at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17380:23)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6454:29)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6436:25)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:4:53)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14725:29)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14702:56)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14625:31)
        at RuntimeCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17420:43)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17390:37)
        at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17380:23)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6454:29)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6436:25)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:4:53)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

Please help me in this.

hero-design.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { hero1 } from './hero1';

  @Component({
       moduleId: module.id,
       selector : 'my-design',
       templateUrl : 'hero-design.component.html',
       styleUrls : ['hero-design.component.css']
  })

 export class HeroDesignComponent{

 subjects = ['Appointment', 'Interview', 'regarding a post'];

 model =new  hero1(1,'Tony','tony@gmail.com','9988776655',this.subjects[0]);

 submitted = false;

 onsubmit() { this.submitted = true }

 newhero1() {
 this.model = new hero1(1,'','','','');
 }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }        from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule }      from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }     from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDesignComponent } from './hero-design.component';
import { HeroService }         from './Hero.service';
import { DashboardComponent }  from './dashboard.component';
import { AppRoutingModule }    from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({ 
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
    ],

  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDesignComponent
    ],

   providers:[
     HeroService
   ],

  bootstrap:    [ 
    AppComponent 
   ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: If you don't share the related code how can we know what's wrong?

Comment: share your app module file code

Comment: Please provide specific Angular and Webpack versions. Also, this might help you https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11438